# Just CANNOT install ember-cli with npm

Tags: npm, ember-cli

I'm running on mac osx yosemite 10.10.5 & this is what I get whenever I hit `npm install -g ember-cli`

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/itsfadnis/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/bin/iojs" "/Users/itsfadnis/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.3.1/bin/npm" "install" "-g"     "ember-cli" "--no-optional"
npm ERR! node v3.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 103.245.222.162:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/itsfadnis/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried the following and none have worked:

1. Reinstall node and npm
2. `npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org`
3. Tried with different versions of node - v0.12.8, iojs-v3.3.1, v4.4.2, v5.0
4. Without optional dependencies `npm install -g ember-cli`
5. As administrator `sudo npm install -g ember-cli`

Network connection is absolutely fine and I'm not behind a proxy.
Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Turns out it was failing due to a firewall enabled on my router. Disabling it did the trick!

Comment: Can you connect to the address shown in the log? 103.245.222.162:80

Comment: @JoséLuis nope, it says unknown domain.

Comment: The problem seems to be with npm not nodejs so try to reinstall npm, clean npm cache.

Comment: @DanielKmak Yes I have tried both of what you have suggested. Still no luck.

Comment: --cache-min 999999
I had a similar problem,
in my case I solved by adding this option
please let me know if it works so I can formulate  a complete answer

Comment: have you found a answer?